# Is it possible to do "reverse" prefix search

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with these columns:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a.b |
| 3 | a.b.c |
| 4 | a.b.c.d |
| 5 | d |
| 6 | d.e |
| 7 | d.e.f |

If I run query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
```

I can get `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`.  However, is it possible to do the **reverse**, such as:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE prefix_match(name, 'a.b.c')
```

which will return `1`, `2`, `3`, but **not** `4`.

Does MySQL have such `prefix_match` logic?

Comment: I am a bit confused, could you explain what do you mean by prefix match?

Comment: i.e. given `a.bc.def`, I want it to return `a.bc.def`, `a.bc` and `a`, but NOT `a.b`, or any string that does not start with `a` of course.  So prefix is sort like the domain system. The accepted answer is purly in the sense of string prefix, but not "dot-separated" prefix. but anyway, I will get over this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE 'a.b.c' LIKE concat(name, '%')
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=484dc7c4acee09de5129c4ebe1b47edf

Comment: this does **NOT** work, because there are data with other prefixes, I will update the question

Comment: @xrfang The second option still gave the right results. See the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM `names` WHERE SUBSTR('a.b.c', 1, LENGTH(name)) = name
```

This will select all the IDs whose corresponding `name` begins with a substring of 'a.b.c', but only for names that are not longer than 'a.b.c' (5 chars).

Comment: this answer is same as the accepted. however **both** has some problem with my actual problem at hand. :-)